# How to place a Show/Hide toggle button next to a header (not under the header)?

Tags: jquery, css, html, togglebutton

I have made a toggle button, and I was trying to style it so that it sits just next to a header (it can be a header or a paragraph with few words). I designed it with CSS  and tried my best to do that. Whatever I design, the button always stays under the header. But I want to place it next to the header.
How to do that?

.HTML:

```
<p id="my_short_biography"><b>MY SHORT BIOGRAPHY</b>      

</p>       

<div id ="button_size">

<button id="button_position"><p id="show_hide">Show / Hide</p></button>

</div>
```

.CSS:

```
    #button_size{
    text-align:center;
    }

    #button_position{
    margin-top:10px;
    cursor:pointer; /*forces the cursor to change to a hand when the button is hovered*/

    background:#35b128; /*the colour of the button*/
    border:1px solid #33842a; /*required or the default border for the browser will appear*/
    /*give the button curved corners, alter the size as required*/
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*give the button a drop shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    /*style the text*/
    color:#f3f3f3;

    height:26px;
    }

    #button_position:hover,#button_position:focus{
    background-color :#399630; /*make the background a little darker*/
    /*reduce the drop shadow size to give a pushed button effect*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    }

#my_short_biography{
font-size:25px;
color:#FF9900;
margin-left:98px;
margin-right:98px;
font-family:Mistral;
text-shadow:3px 3px 3px green;
text-decoration:underline;

}

#show_hide{
font-size:19.5px;
color:#FF9900;
font-family:Gergia;
text-shadow:3px 3px 3px green;


}
```

.JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#toggle").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the button inside the `<header>` or `<p>` tag:

```
<p> PARAGRAPH
   <button>BUTTON</button>
</p>
```